# Applying distinct on more than one field?

Tags: t-sql

I have a SQL query, like so:

SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name FROM Table

This brings up all the distinct IDs (1...13), but in the 13 IDs, it repeats the name (as it comes up twice). The order of the query (ID, Name) has to be kept the same as the app using this query is coded with this assumption.

Is there a way to ensure there are no duplicates?

Thanks

Comment: Distinct applies to all of the columns.  If there are duplicates, then they must only "appear" to be duplicates.  Maybe there is a space after the name or another hidden character like tab, cr, lf, etc...

Comment: That distinct should apply to both fields. Are you sure your name field that is duplicated is identical? Try running `select distinct ID, lower(rtrim(ltrim(Name))) as Name from Table` and see if you still get duplicates.

Comment: Please let me pretend to be a little dumb for a while and ask you this silly question: do the duplicate names have identical or different IDs? I'm just not sure about that from your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
select id, name from table group by id,name
```

But it seems like distinct should work.  Perhaps there are trailing spaces at the end of your name fields?

Comment: trailing spaces are ignored in string comparisons. Maybe trailing tabs or other non printing characters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `DISTINCT`, use `GROUP BY`

```
 SELECT ID, Name FROM Table GROUP BY ID, Name
```